# Display current vote tally with popup achievements summary

Tags: feature-request, achievements-dialog, score

Currently, the achievement popup displays the net reputation delta derived from posts grouped by question title, eg

> +25 Some question title
> +10 Some other question title
> +20 Some old question title

#### As well as the *delta*, it would be good to show the post's current vote breakdown, eg

> +25 (✓1/0) Some question title
> +10 (2/5) Some other question title
> +20 (24/0) Some old question title

(The tick means "accepted')

#### Why?

Unfortunate arithmetic:
Note the second example: Without the extra info, we will likely think we got 1 upvote and leave it at that, but actually we got 2 up and 5 down votes and so should investigate the apparent problem with the post.

Interest (to avoid score curiosity click through):
You notice you're got quite a few votes for a post and are curious as to its score, but to find that out you have to open the question (and you *only* want to see the score and nothing else). With the extra info, you don't need to click through - you can see you're 1 upvote away from a "Good answer"

Implementation detail:

The edge case of someone answering their own question could be handled by splitting into two vote summaries, perhaps:

> +15 (Q:3/0 A:5/1) Some self-answered question title

---

The exact format of the vote data would likely be the subject of a UX debate. This question is more about whether it the vote data should be shown or not - not so much how to show it, although ideas are welcome.

Comment: How does this play into sites where we don't have the privilege to view up-/down-vote ratios? If I remember correctly, that applies to your own posts as well as those by others.

Comment: And in addition to what @MatthewHaugen said, it is an expensive query to run, which is why the privilege exists in the first place, and why it's only on-demand.